# How to implement the functionality of the asort function without using the keyword asort()?

Tags: php

This is my simple code.

```
    <?php
     $num=array('a'=>5, 'b'=>3, 'c'=>1);
    ?>
```

How to sort this array while maintaining index association witout using asort()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check Custom_asort() Example

```
   <?php

/* Custom asort function */
function custom_asort($num)
{
    $return = $numbers = array();   // empty array 
    foreach($num as $key => $val)
    {
        $numbers[] = $val ;
    }
    sort($numbers);  // sort number 
    $arrlength = count($numbers);   // count array lenght 
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        $key = array_search($numbers[$x], $num);      // array_search apply for search key according to index 
        $return[$key] = $numbers[$x]; 
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($return);  // print function output 
}
$num=array('a'=>5, 'b'=>3, 'c'=>1, 'd'=>2);   // array 
custom_asort($num);  // calling function 
?>
```

Comment: While you have sorted the values, you have changed their indexes as well. If you could sort them while maintaining their index associations, it would be great.

Comment: Welcome@AdityaThakur

Comment: if this answer is useful then please add as useful also ... :)http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!